# What is the xpath for the following text (error message) in selenium webdriver?

Tags: selenium, webdriver

I have the following HTML snippet:

```
  <div class="alert alert-danger">
     <button class="close" type="button" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
    User name or password are incorrect
   </div>
```

[image]

What will be the xpath to find the "*User name or password are incorrect*" text ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String WrongUsernameMessage = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='alert alert-danger']")).getText();
    String[] WUmessage= WrongUsernameMessage.split("\n");
    //System.out.println(message[1]);
    if (WUmessage[1].equals("User name or password are incorrect"))
       {
     System.out.println("Message is CORRECT.");
       }else{
     System.out.println("Message is INCORRECT.");
       }
```

This is working.

Answer (score 1):

Use Following `xpath` to get the message -

```
String message = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//div[@class='alert alert-danger']")).getText();
```

or You can try using `cssSelector` as well

```
String message = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.alert.alert-danger")).getText();
```

It returns your message with button text `x` . Use following code to get only message -

```
  String message = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//div[@class='alert alert-danger']")).getText();
  String finalMessage = message.replace("x", "").trim();
```

**Edited**

```
Thread.sleep(2000);
String message = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//div[@class='alert alert-danger']")).getText();
String finalMessage = message.replace("x", "").trim();      
if(finalMessage.equals("User name or password are incorrect"))
{ 
    System.out.println("Message is CORRECT."); 
}
else
{ 
    System.out.println("Message is INCORRECT."); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply Narendra: this ie giving error:There is an error in XML document (1, 33).also still giving value x

Comment: `String WrongUsernameMessage = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//div[@class='login-content']/div/div")).getText();
 if (WrongUsernameMessage.equals("User name or password are incorrect"))
    {
  System.out.println("Message is CORRECT.");
    }else{
  System.out.println("Message is INCORRECT.");
       } `
 this is my code. and its giving result: Message is INCORRECT. while it should display Message is CORRECT.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this xPath:

```
String message = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//div[@class='login-content']/div/div")).getText();
```

Comment: `String WrongUsernameMessage = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//div[@class='login-content']/div/div")).getText();
 if (WrongUsernameMessage.equals("User name or password are incorrect"))
    {
  System.out.println("Message is CORRECT.");
    }else{
  System.out.println("Message is INCORRECT.");
       } `
 this is my code. and its giving result: Message is INCORRECT. while it should display Message is CORRECT.